# Ability to like the post just one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm working on the new ability on my RoR application. I've implemented the like/dislike system and now i'd like to add the ability to like the post just one time( User 1 can like or dislike the Post 2 just one time). How can i make this. I thought, that i can make it just like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 # validates :avatar, attachment_presence: true
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts

  def admin?
    admin
  end

end

 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

but besides of that i need one more field this has_and_belongs_to_many model, which will be the boolean field, that tells me if true - it is liked, false - it is disliked. BUt how can i access this field in this model. i do not have any idea ? Could you help me ?

my schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151223102401) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.text    "text"
    t.integer "like",    default: 0
    t.integer "dislike", default: 0
  end

  create_table "posts_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.boolean "like"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Comment: Posting your db schema would be helpful.

Comment: I editet it, check out

Comment: Ok, check my answer. If it helps, please upvote and accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider of using some libraries? there is a gem 'act_as_votable' which do exactly what you want. And it's pretty good documented. Here is a link to repo on github and documentation about registered votes https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#registered-votes

Comment: I use this.  This is the answer.

Comment: No, i'd like to make it without additional libraries

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have 3 models; User, Post and PostUser.

And, you want:

1. Allow a user to create a post
2. Allow a user to like or dislike the post only one time
3. If the user already like or dislike the post, hide the like or dislike button
4. Upon liking or disliking a post, add `like` or `dislike` value inside `posts` table for that post

Okay, this is my solution to tackle this kind of situation.

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151226094953) do

  create_table "post_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "already_like_or_dislike", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                              null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "text"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "like",       default: 0
    t.integer  "dislike",    default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

**Post model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :post_users
end
```

**PostUser model**

```
class PostUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**User model (generated by Devise gem)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :posts
  has_many :post_users
end
```

Okay, now let's take a look at controller actions.

First, I add 2 new actions to `set_post` action: `like` and `dislike`:

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like, :dislike]

private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**show action**

```
def show
    if user_signed_in?
      if @post.post_users.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
        @can_like_or_dislike = false
      else
        @can_like_or_dislike = true
      end
    end
  end
```

First, we check if the user is signed-in or not. If user is signed-in, we try to find a record inside `post_users` table where `post_id: @post.id` and `user_id: current_user.id`.

If we found a record, that means, that signed-in user already liked or disliked the post. So, we passed `false` to the `@can_like_or_dislike` variable.

And this is how our show template looks like:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% if @can_like_or_dislike %>
        <%= link_to "Like", like_post_path, method: :post %>
        <%= link_to "Dislike", dislike_post_path, method: :post %>
    <% else %>
        You already like or dislike this post
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now, let's create 2 new route endpoints to handle like and dislike POST request like so:

```
resources :posts do
    post 'like', on: :member, as: 'like'
    post 'dislike', on: :member, as: 'dislike'
  end
```

Now, we have 2 new route (run `rake routes`):

```
like_post    POST   /posts/:id/like(.:format)      posts#like
dislike_post POST   /posts/:id/dislike(.:format)   posts#dislike
```

So, we need to create 2 new actions named `like` and `dislike` inside our posts controller like so:

```
def like
    @post.post_users.create(post_id: @post.id, user_id: current_user.id, already_like_or_dislike: true)
    current_post_like = @post.like
    new_post_like = current_post_like + 1
    @post.update_attributes(like: new_post_like)
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def dislike
    @post.post_users.create(post_id: @post.id, user_id: current_user.id, already_like_or_dislike: true)
    current_post_dislike = @post.dislike
    new_post_dislike = current_post_dislike + 1
    @post.update_attributes(dislike: new_post_dislike)
    redirect_to @post
  end
```

Let me explain what happened inside `like` action.

First, we create a record inside `post_users` table, passing current user ID and that post ID. And, for `already_like_or_dislike`, we change it from default `false` to `true`.

Next, we update that post's `like` column from current value to plus one (+1) value. Example, from `0` to `1`.

Next, we redirect back to the show template.

For the `dislike` action, it's pretty similar. What's the difference is, we update the `dislike` column inside `posts` table rather than `like` column.

That's all.

And for `new` and `create` action, it's bit different now:

```
def new
    @post = current_user.posts.new
  end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

    ...
  end
```

Since we have association a User `has_many :posts` and a Post belongs_to a User, we can simply init `Post` `.new` instance from User object (`current_user`).

Doing this will automatically add `user_id: 1` for example when we create a `Post` record and we don't need to create a hidden field inside the form and make the value equal to the current signed-in user ID.

You can [check full source code of this little app here inside my Github repo](https://github.com/zulhfreelancer/like_post_just_one_time).

Demo video of the result: https://youtu.be/iHp_tIRzrPo